# joomla mysql cannot see database via workbench

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, mysql-workbench

We have a joomla site up and running using a user called 'product_joomla' and a database with the same name.

I am able to connect to the mysql server using the that user above and password.

But I can only see the 'information_schema' database. the user does not seem to have access to the joomla database.

But that does not seem to be the case because the joomla site is using the same user and is working.

I am total noob with respect to mysql and joomla.

I am accessing the mysql database remotely via mysql-workbench.

I cannot figure out why that user cannot see the joomla database via workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Even though we changed the user to accept connections from anywhere (not just localhost) that never updated the actual permissions on the joomla database – users still only granted admin rights if that user logged in from localhost.

So, the website was working via localhost but I was not able to connect remotely.